# Ms Excel: Is there any way to superscript a character in custom format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, microsoft-office

I want to display the measuring unit (cubic meters) in the cell using custom format ( #.##0,00" m3"), but I want to superscript the character "3". Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 7):

You can add superscript numbers in custom formatting using superscript shortcuts:

[image: Superscript in custom formatting in Excel]

In order to type a superscript 3, you need to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then press 0179 (on the numeric keyboard!). If you use a laptop without numeric keyboard, you need to activate <kbd>num lock</kbd>.

You can type the following superscript numbers using this method:

1: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 0185

2: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 0178

3: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 0179